# Salesforce Mobile SDK for secure offline storage

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am new to develop a Salesforce Mobile SDK for secure offline storage in salesforce1 custom mobile app, I want a step by step by procedure how to implement it.

Comment: Have you already try something ?